Identify 6-pin SMD component marked TT3cb1 from Asus AX4200 router

I need to identify an SMT 6-pin component, which is marked TT3cb1
It is from Asus AX4200 router PCB.

Chipyto - Hi, Can you help by adding more info about where on that router's PCB this IC came from - e.g. a photo of that area of the PCB showing surrounding components & PCB tracks? Have you done any reverse-engineering of the circuit around that component, or any other analysis? If so, please add those details. I guess it's a SOT-23-6 package, but please also add its measurements. More info about what can help with identification here. TY

Thank you for all replies.
Yes, surely is.
I am going to buy it. Thanks to all. Carlos

This is likely TMI3253T from TOLL Microelectronic. It is a DC-DC Step-down converter in a SOT23-6 package.
From the datasheet, it has the following marking and pinout:

The first three digits TT3 indicate it is TMI3253T, with the remaining three digits being as date code.
Image searches for that part number show similar marking styles.
Without photographs of the PCB and surrounding circuitry, it is not possible to be certain as there is no way to verify the pin-out matches.
